# why js can Improved code efficiency use function?

Tags: javascript, performance, mongodb

When I use mongodb in js,I found the code's efficiency is different between example1(122ms) and example2(390ms),example1 put the code in function() but example2 not.    why?

## example1:

```
var timePage2 = function(){
    var start = (new Date()).getTime();
    var page1;
    for(var i= 0; i < 10000; i++){        
            page1 = db.test.find({"n":{"$gt":i*100}}).limit(100); 
    }
    var end = (new Date()).getTime();
    var timeDiff = end - start;
     print("Update took2:" + timeDiff+"ms");
}

timePage2()
```

## example2:

```
 //var timePage2 = function(){
    var start = (new Date()).getTime();
    var page1;
    for(var i= 0; i < 10000; i++){        
            page1 = db.test.find({"n":{"$gt":i*100}}).limit(100); 
    }
    var end = (new Date()).getTime();
    var timeDiff = end - start;
     print("Update took2:" + timeDiff+"ms");
//    }

//     timePage2()
```

Comment: i asume this has alot to do with the function scope.

Comment: Doesn't `db.test.find` search for a record in the database? How do you know the time you recorded is spend in your JavaScript and not searching in the database?